# Attempting to make text appear on "mouseover"

Tags: javascript, html

New to javascript, and I am attempting to make text appear below an image when the user mouses over it. For the HTML, I have created an empty sub tag with the id 'subtext' () below two images, and I am attempting to use a for loop, and if else statement to have a specific message occupy the subtext depending on which image is experiencing "mouseover".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        let picture = document.querySelectorAll('.picture');
            for (let i = 0; i <picture.length; i++) {
                picture.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                var text;
                var pictureid = picture.getElementById();
                if (pictureid === '#pic1') {
                    text = 'First response';
                } else {
                    text = 'Second response';
                }
                document.getElementById('#subtext').innerHTML = text;
            }
    )};
});
    
    </script>

    <body>
        <img src="IMG_1.jpg" width="300" height="400" class = picture id="pic1">
        <img src="IMG_2.jpg" width="300" height="400" class = picture id ="pic2">
        <sub id="subtext"></sub>
    </body>
</html>
```

[See here for error message - that I am missing a semicolon and have an unnecessary one at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNiiz.png)

Comment: The curly braces should come before parenthesis. Change `)};` to `});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **js** code contains errors. Also, in the **html** structure, you did not wrap the class names in quotation marks. Like that:

```
class = picture
```

instead of `for`, I used the `forEach()` method in which I determined the current image:

```
picture.forEach(function (picture_current, index) {
        picture_current.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        ...
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let picture = document.querySelectorAll('.picture');

    picture.forEach(function (picture_current, index) {
        picture_current.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            var text;
            var pictureid = this.getAttribute('id');
        if (pictureid === 'pic1') {
          text = 'First response';
        } else {
          text = 'Second response';
        }
            document.querySelector('#subtext').innerHTML = text;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <img src="IMG_1.jpg" width="300" height="400" class="picture" id="pic1">
      <img src="IMG_2.jpg" width="300" height="400" class="picture" id ="pic2">
      <sub id="subtext"></sub>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @THARP, no problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of typos but biggest problem was querySelectorAll returns an array

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
   

    <body>
        <img src="IMG_1.jpg" width="300" height="400" class = picture id="pic1">
        <img src="IMG_2.jpg" width="300" height="400" class = picture id ="pic2">
        <sub id="subtext"></sub>
        
        
        
         <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        let picture = document.querySelectorAll('.picture');
            for (let i = 0; i <picture.length; i++) {
                picture[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
                var text;
                
                var pictureid = picture[i].id;
                if (pictureid === 'pic1') {
                    text = 'First response';
                } else {
                    text = 'Second response';
                }
                document.getElementById('subtext').innerHTML = text;
            }
    )};
});
    
    </script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```